# How Do I Center Items In Navigation Bar in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm re-creating the Apple website as homework for a class.
Here is the GitHub repository: [Repository](https://github.com/NotDiamondZ/homework). I used Bootstrap in it to get that Apple feel. Later on, I see that the navigation is centered.[image: Navigation]
Unlike mine
[image: my site]
A friend of mine told me something `position: relative` and `left: 50%`

## Update 1:

He told me to add `position: relative; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)` to the ul tag. I tried it but it didn't work.

## Update 2:

Turns out I didn't have the CSS file linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have fixed your issue, replace your html with my code and keep your Css original.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Apple</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png" type="image/png">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Apple">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark d-flex  justify-content-center">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/img/apple.png" width="20"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav"> 
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#" style="color: white">Mac</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white">iPad</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white">iPhone</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white; text-align: center">Watch</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white; text-align: center">TV</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white; text-align: center">Music</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white; text-align: center">Support</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35be2e4c40.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey I am not that good at CSS but try this in a style tag or CSS file hope this works

```
    ul{
      margin:0 auto;
   }
```

this will center that 'ul' in the navbar. if you want more space between each element then try adding

```
li{
   margin-left:<anyvalue>%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use flexbox utilities, in line 19  `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">` add this class `justify-content-center` too, you can test other flexbox classes:

```
<div class="justify-content-start">...</div>
<div class="justify-content-end">...</div>
<div class="justify-content-center">...</div>
<div class="justify-content-between">...</div>
<div class="justify-content-around">...</div>
<div class="justify-content-evenly">...</div>
```

for more information check this link [flexbox-bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content)